# How to route posts from firebase to its own section in polymer?

Tags: html, firebase, polymer-1.0, web-component

im struggling with some issues regarding routing blog posts from firebase, which i previously pushed it using paper-input and firebase-elements.
this is my code of the custom element:

```
<firebase-collection
  location="https://sm-design.firebaseio.com/Blog"
  data="{{blog}}"></firebase-collection>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[blog]]" as="blog">
<a href="{{baseUrl}}blog/{{blog.link}}"><h1>[[blog.titlu]]</h1></a>
<img src="/images/[[blog.imagine]]">
<p>[[blog.body]]</p>
</template>
```

and this is the routing:

```
page('/blog/{{blog.link}}', function() {
  app.route = '{{blog.link}}';


});
```

this is the section:

```
  <section data-route="{{blog.link}}">

            </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routes can contain parameters, which you can assess through the context parameter to your route handler

```
page('/blog/:link', function(context) {
    app.route = context.params.link;
});
```

Observe the link property of `blog` for changes

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#observing-path-changes

```
observers: [
    'linkChanged(blog.link)'
],
linkChanged: function(link) {
    page('/blog/' + link);
}
```

Comment: I understand that data-binding doesn't work, but I still cannot make it work, I don't understand how to make the routing using data from firebase.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I don't know if I fully understand your question. I am assuming that you want to get data(blog) from firebase and then navigate to '/blog/' + blog.link